# EditText to String to double conversion and calculating error

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, double

I'm writing an app that calculates the average of your marks. Here's the code that calculates it:

```
btrechnen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        result = (Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e7.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e8.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e9.getText().toString())+
        Integer.parseInt(e10.getText().toString())) /10;

        String resstring = Double.toString(result);
        tvrechnen.setText(resstring);
    }
});
```

Now, the problem is that the `TextView` shows only full numbers like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 instead of showing 1.54, 3.6 etc.

Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: You're adding the numbers as integers. Use `Double.parseDouble()` instead.

Comment: Thx that worked

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String floatValue = "14.459054";
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(floatValue));
```

Result:

```
14.459054
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change /10 to /10**f** and you'll get needed results